# spawning threads in c++ safely

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I am starting to play with threads... I wrote a `test_function` inside my class that spawns threads:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

class Strategy {
public:
    void test_function();
    virtual Strategy* clone() const { 
        return new Strategy(*this);
    }
private:
    void do_work(Strategy*);
    int example_counter = 0;
    inline static std::mutex __mutex;
    inline static int n_threads = 1;   
};

void Strategy::test_function() {
    clock_t __start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        Strategy* copy = clone();
        auto thread_function = [&] {
            do_work(copy);
            clock_t end = clock();
            double duration = (end - __start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            std::lock_guard lock(__mutex);
            std::cout << "Thread took " << duration << "s\n";
        };
        if (n_threads < std::thread::hardware_concurrency()) {
            ++n_threads;
            std::thread perm([&] { thread_function(); --n_threads; }); 
            perm.detach();
        } else thread_function();
    }
}

void Strategy::do_work(Strategy* copy) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        ++copy->example_counter;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    std::lock_guard lock(__mutex);
    example_counter = copy->example_counter;
    delete copy;
}

int main() {
    Strategy test;
    test.test_function();
    return 0;
}
```

note: `Strategy` is a pure virtual class, it needs this `clone()` virtual function to make a dinamic copy of itself...

I though that checking the number of threads spawned would limit them, but it does not and i get a segfault.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Unrelated to question, but all identifiers containing double underscores are reserved to the compiler and standard library in _all_ contexts and must not be used for other purposes. Using them anyway is technically UB and can result in some quite unusual bugs/errors.

Comment: If you get a segfault, inspect the stack trace and see where exactly did it crash.

Comment: @user17732522 should i name my stuff with a single _underscore if i want to convey their private aspect?

Comment: @ugo_capeto That's one possible convention. But note that single underscore at the beginning is also generally reserved in the global namespace scope and single underscore followed by upper-case letter is also reserved in _all_ contexts. So only single underscore followed by lower-case letter or digit.

Comment: Your thread function is accessing the `copy` pointer variable by reference-capture, while its scope ends without any synchronization. That doesn't work. You'll need to capture by-copy instead. I don't know whether this is the only issue. Please form a proper [mre]. Also, in general it is not a good idea to detach threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very subtle bug:

```
        Strategy* copy = clone();
        auto thread_function = [&] {
```

But thread functions that capture variables by reference are very prone to undefined behavior when the captured references go out of scope.

`copy` is being captured by reference via `[&]`, but it's a local variable within a scope.  And `copy` goes out of scope very quickly after the thread is launched. Even though `copy` itself is a valid pointer, the pointer to copy is effectively going away in a race condition with the thread trying to access it.

Capture the variables you need by value:

```
        Strategy* copy = clone();
        auto thread_function = [copy, __start] {
```

I see `__iterations` getting modified within your thread, but I couldn't tell if that was a local or a global variable. You could potentially pass it by reference, but its lifetime needs to be understood.

Access to the global variables should still work and not need capturing.

Another bug:

```
++n_threads;
std::thread perm([&] { thread_function(); --n_threads; }); 
    perm.detach();
```

You are touching `n_threads` within the thread without entering the mutex. This can create other subtle bugs.  Just decrement `n_threads` within the thread function while you are still within the mutex.

The other thing I noticed is explicitly invoking `detach` on your thread. If you are new to threads, that's probably not a good pattern to start with unless you really know what you are doing.  You probably need something that waits for all threads to finish:

So instead of this:

```
std::thread perm([&] { thread_function(); --n_threads; }); 
    perm.detach();
```

This:

```
std::thread perm(thread_function);

threads.push_back(std::move(perm));
```

Where `threads` is a `std::vector<std::thread>` declared at a sufficient scope so that all the work can be safely confirmed as done like this:

```
for (auto &t : threads) {
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: You can also write `[=]` to capture anything you need by value, but you may accidentally copy something unexpectedly, just like you referenced something unexpectedly with `[&]`

Comment: thank you for the kind answer, it really helped a lot, i am new to threading and lambdas as you saw. one more thing if i may ask. why do i need this std::move, what is it?

Comment: You can't "assign" or "copy" a thread variable (i.e. t1 = t2).  You can only transfer ownership of the internals between variables. Hence, std::move is required to add a thread to a vector.